# add rows in data frame by sequence and fill rows appropriately

Tags: r

I have a very large data frame consisting of a series of actions and time stamps of the actions.

For reproducibility, it looks similar to the output of this...

```
df <- data.frame(1:10)
df[,1] = c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4")
colnames(df) = c("Clock")
df$client = c("1")
df$action = c("0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "0", "1", "0")
df$experimenter = c("NP", "NP", "NP", "NP", "NP", "TU", "TU", "TU", "TU", "TU")

## output
   Clock client action experimenter
      0      1      0           NP
      1      1      1           NP
      2      1      0           NP
      3      1      0           NP
      4      1      0           NP
      0      1      1           TU
      1      1      1           TU
      2      1      0           TU
      3      1      1           TU
      4      1      0           TU
```

How can I do the following:

1) add lines between the numbers in the clock column (for 1/4 seconds)?

2) fill in the data appropriately for the near column?

The output would look something like this...

```
 Clock client action experimenter
      0      1      0           NP
      0.25   1      0           NP
      0.50   1      0           NP
      0.75   1      0           NP
      1      1      1           NP
      1.25   1      1           NP
      1.50   1      1           NP
      1.75   1      1           NP
      2      1      0           NP
      2.25   1      0           NP
      2.50   1      0           NP
      2.75   1      0           NP
      3      1      0           NP
      3.25   1      0           NP
      3.50   1      0           NP
      3.75   1      0           NP
      4      1      0           NP
      4.25   1      0           NP
      4.50   1      0           NP
      4.75   1      0           NP
      0      1      1           TU
      0.25   1      1           TU
      0.50   1      1           TU
      0.75   1      1           TU
      1      1      1           TU
      1.25   1      1           TU
      1.50   1      1           TU
      1.75   1      1           TU
      2      1      0           TU
      2.25   1      0           TU
      2.50   1      0           TU
      2.75   1      0           TU
      3      1      1           TU
      3.25   1      1           TU
      3.50   1      1           TU
      3.75   1      1           TU
      4      1      0           TU
      4.25   1      0           TU
      4.50   1      0           TU
      4.75   1      0           TU
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `complete` and `fill` after creating groups in the data. For each group we create a sequence from the minimum value in the `Clock` to maximum + 0.75 and then `fill` all the missing values by previous non-NA values.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate_at(1:3, as.numeric) %>%
  group_by(group = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(Clock) < 0))) %>%
  complete(Clock = seq(min(Clock), max(Clock) + 0.75, by = 0.25)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-group) %>%
  fill(everything())

# A tibble: 40 x 4
#   Clock client action experimenter
#   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>       
# 1  0         1      0 NP          
# 2  0.25      1      0 NP          
# 3  0.5       1      0 NP          
# 4  0.75      1      0 NP          
# 5  1         1      1 NP          
# 6  1.25      1      1 NP          
# 7  1.5       1      1 NP          
# 8  1.75      1      1 NP          
# 9  2         1      0 NP          
#10  2.25      1      0 NP          
# … with 30 more rows
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R solution would be to repeat the rows and then add fractions to the `Clock` variable:

```
df2 <- df[rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), each=4),]
df2$Clock <- as.numeric(df2$Clock) + ((0:3)/4)
```